# In J2me using LWUIT Library, how to place command button forcefully on right side of mobile screen?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

How can I place a command button forcefully on right side of mobile screen? In j2me, I am using LWUIT library.

In my form I want to add only one command i.e. back command. This back command must be placed on right side of the screen. What is the necessary code for this?

Comment: how can done this? and what is benifit

Answer (score 7):

```
UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().setReverseSoftButtons(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `setReverseSoftbuttons(true)` in the look and feel or the form.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
Command command= new Command("OK", okImage, 1);
Command dummy= new Command(" ", -1);
listMessagesForm.addCommand(dummy);
listMessagesForm.addCommand(command);
```